# Authenticating with ADAL JS not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, adal.js

I have two Azure AD applications in the same directory, let’s call them `FrontendAuth` and `BackendAuth`, which provide authentication for an ASP.NET MVC frontend and a Web API backend, respectively. The MVC frontend is protected using the standard `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` configuration, the Web API backend with `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication`.

What I want to do is log into the frontend, authenticate against `FrontendAuth`, then consume via JavaScript the API hosted in the backend by providing a token, acquired using `ADAL JS`, to `BackendAuth`.

**Assumptions**

My expectations/assumptions are:

- That I would have to configure `FrontendAuth` to have access to `BackendAuth` in the classic portal
- That I would have to edit the manifest files of one or both of these to set `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` to `true`
- That when I configure `ADAL JS` I should be setting `clientId` to be that of `FrontendAuth`
- The `endpoints` object of the `ADAL JS` configuration should contain the Url of the backend API and the client ID of `BackendAuth`

**Outcome**

I can achieve my goal of logging in to the frontend and communicating with the backend service via `ADAL JS` with:

- The `FrontendAuth` application having no access to `BackendAuth` at all
- Neither manifest file having the `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` property set to `true`
- `ADAL JS` having the `clientId` set to be that of `BackendAuth`
- The endpoints object of the `ADAL JS` configuration not set at all

**Questions**

Based on these findings I would like to understand the following:

- Were my assumptions correct? Is this how `ADAL JS` is intended to work?
- Why did the lack of application access and unchanged manifest files have no effect on whether the authentication succeeded?
- When do these measures have an effect on the authentication outcome?

Comment: `FrontEndAuth` would need `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow:true` in its manifest. This is not required for the `BackEndAuth`s manifest

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two OAuth2 flows here ([authorization code flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) and [implicit flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2)). Both are meant to issue a token to a client application. The auth code flow is used for web apps running on the server (like your MVC app) and the implicit flow is meant for public clients like a SPA.

When you use [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) to sign in your user to your MVC application, using the hybrid flow, you receive an authorization code from the browser. You use this code to talk to the authorization server and get a JWT token which is then stored in a cookie session. You can use the same code to get a JWT token for your BackendAuth app, as long as you have given permission to your FrontendAuth app to call the BackendAuth app.

If you want to enable the JavaScript in the user's browser to call into the BackendAuth app, you'll need to somehow pass the access token to the browser. You can do this by sending the token along with the initial request and put it in local storage or expose a (secured) MVC route to get the token.

For an example of what I'm describing here see [this Azure AD sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs), which acquires a token for the Graph API using the authorization code is received.

ADAL.js implements the implicit flow and is meant for JavaScript applications like SPAs etc.

Comment: I'm aware of the difference between the two flows (and I'm already getting a token from the Graph API with my authorization code), what I'd really like to know is why I can call the backend service when the manifest files remain unchanged and the frontend Azure AD app has no permission to the backend one - the documentation stated both are necessary.

Comment: @nick_w Check the 'aud' claim in the JWT token used to authenticate with the backend. You can use https://jwt.io to decode the token.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't explicitly decorated your Web API controllers with [Authorize] attributes (either at the class level, or the action level). Thus, your Web API may be happy to serve content to anyone who requests it.